# how to return an object in a map function (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I have some user input, I need to split them into characters, then just using map to return both the character array and index array as an object. Try many ways but all failed. Hope I can get some helps here. I am new to react.js and my code may sounds dum. The code is in App.js the main component.

```
  charList = () => { 
    this.state.userInputs.split("").map((ch1, index1) => 
    { return {ch: ch1, index: index1}
    } ); 
  }
```

I want to be able to access this.charList.ch and this.charList.index for the two arrays. Not sure I described my question clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need index of characters?

Comment: Good question, I know it is dum, but I am following a Udemy course on React.js where the teacher simply use this as an assignment that may not make sense in real life.  :)

Comment: `.map((ch, index) => ({ ch, index }))` would work as well. [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a function that receives array item, index and full array and returns the mapped item so `[1,2].map(i=>i*3)` the function `i=>i*3` receives 1 and then 2 and will return 3 and 6 resulting in `[3,6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like this:

```
[
  { "ch": "h", "index": 0 },
  { "ch": "i", "index": 1 }
]
```

You're just missing a `return` before `this.state.userInputs.split("")`

```
charList = () => { 
    return this.state.userInputs.split("").map((ch1, index1) => {
        return {ch: ch1, index: index1 }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes you understood exactly what I wanted. Thank you! so what is the first 'return' actually doing? I guess the 2nd 'return' is to assign values to the fields of the object, so the 1st 'return' is to return the whole object to charList? also, I don't understand why the code below is not showing me the result: ~~~  
    render() 
        { return ( <div> <p> {this.charList.ch} </p> </div> ); }
~~~
oops, first time here, don't even know how to format the code.

Comment: You got it (mostly!) - the second return is returning each _object_, the outer return is returning the entire _array_. You won't be able to render `this.charList` without a few changes. 1) `this.charList` seems to be a method on the class, so you'll need to call it like `{this.charList()}` 2) `charList` returns an array, so you'd have to either `map` over each item to get it's `ch`, or access an item by key (`{this.charList()[0]}`

Comment: And SO doesn't do code blocks in comments, don't worry ;)

Comment: That totally make sense! You also helped me to clarify a few more points that I did not think of. Really appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 return  this.state.userInputs.split("").map((ch1, index1) => 
        { 
            let obj= {};
            obj.ch = ch1; 
            obj.index = index; 
         return obj;
        });
```

Comment: thank you! so what is the 1st "return" actually doing? it appears to me that the 2nd "return" already returned the object back to charList.

Comment: oh, I just realized that the other answer is returning ONE array with each element containing two fields, while your answer is returning TWO arrays with each element in each array containing one field only. So, literally you answered my question exactly, although I did not have a clear mind when I asked the question. Anyway, thank you for your help!